# I need help min, max, last, first value by group mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

My problem is that in the query it works as is, returning the last value of the group

```
SELECT p.promediototalmk
        FROM promediogeneral
        WHERE id IN (
            SELECT MAX(id)
            FROM promediogeneral
            GROUP BY fecha
        ) ORDER BY id DESC
```

but when I do the complete query it returns it is the first value and not the last

```
    SELECT hora,
(SELECT p.promediototalmk FROM promediogeneral GROUP BY fecha ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS OPEN,
(SELECT p.promediototalmk
FROM promediogeneral
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM promediogeneral
    GROUP BY fecha
) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS CLOSE,


    MIN(promediototalmk) AS ProMin, MAX(promediototalmk) AS ProMax, p.`fecha` as FECHA 
FROM promediogeneral p
GROUP BY `fecha` ORDER BY id DESC
```

**RESULT**

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2020-06-15, **>>205881.018<<** ,206615.32,200749.62, **>>205881.018<<** ,0,0
2020-06-14,203554.647,205730.58,199753.08,203554.647,0,0
2020-06-13,201731.652,205091.68,199225.86,201731.652,0,0
```

---

**DB example**

```
fecha      | id | promediototalmk |
2019-02-02 | 1  |  16000.00       | 
2019-02-02 | 2  |  17000.00       |
2019-02-03 | 3  |  14000.00       |
2019-02-01 | 4  |  13000.00       |
2019-02-01 | 5  |  15000.00       |
```

Comment: Hi Luis, it is not very clear honestly, but for example is Fecha a unique value? what are its values? if not, you should use GROUP BY with a unique value so you can be able list the results normally.

Comment: @khader 
the fecha value is repeated
example
2019-12-01
2019-12-01
2019-12-02
2019-12-02

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: *DB example* - replace with its CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO.